# Is there an easy way to route power to the inside of buildings?

Tags: fallout-4

I like all of my smog machines (i.e.: power generators) to be outside of my structures, so as not to suffocate the inhabitants. (Yeah, I know there's not an actual mechanic for that. But stick with me here.)  I also like all of my buildings to be fully enclosed, with solid-looking walls - not those shabby-looking, hole-y walls.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a construction option that allows for this and at the same time permits routing of wires through those walls from the generators. For now, I've been finagling the wires through the slight gap in a section of curved roof. But this tends to be really tricky, requiring extra-special placement of the generator and conduits, and I don't like those types of roofs either.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a "right" or "easy" way to bring power through the walls? (Non-console solutions preferred - I play on XB1.)

Comment: I usually set conduits and/or pylons around the house and place my electrical objects near the walls instead of in the center of the rooms. Electricity have an AoE for bulbs/tvs/etc, you don't need a wire inside. The exception to this is items needing a direct link, like a terminal.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault The issues I have aren't due to objects not being close enough to the conduits. Whenever I have a problem, I verify the conduit is getting power (or not) by hooking a construction light to it with a cable.

Answer (score 3):

Put "wall conduits" (Power > Connectors & Switches) on the inside and outside of the structure, and the power will transmit between them.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident I've tried this to no avail. I specifically remember attempting this recently, when I [built a special facility for my Signal Interceptor](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250737/can-i-build-another-signal-intercepter-after-completing-the-molecular-level), especially because of its large power needs and having certain connectors on the second floor. I ended up putting the generators on the roof and routing it down through the roof access shack. I guess I could still give this another go to be sure.

Comment: You can see an example of this in The Castle, its all set up and ready to use, all you have to do is add the generators.

Comment: Nope, does not work. If you connect a conduit from a generator to a structure like [this](http://i.imgur.com/30yx0RR.jpg) then use another conduit inside right on the other side, it will [not transmit power](http://i.imgur.com/bsyCo0s.jpg)

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault, it does not appear those two conduits are on the same area of wall; Your outside image depicts a conduit approx. 2 units along, while your inside is approx. 5+ units along.

Comment: @Timelord64 Both are on the same wall, the 2nd from the end near the junction with the 1st wall. Then on the inside they are linked in zig-zag towards the TV. Here's a pretty ugly [top-down view](http://i.imgur.com/Go3DZfq.png), grey things being the conduits.

Comment: @Timelord64 Pierre is definitely right about his case. The top-down diagram does help to clarify, but even in the second of the original screenshots it's pretty clear to see that the wire runs all the way back to a wall conduit that's roughly positioned on the opposite side of the same wall as the exterior conduit that's hooked to the generator. This is also particularly helpful to demonstrate my issue, as he's using my preferred wall type.

Comment: @Iszi It might be a problem with the wall type. I can't look at that picture right now, but I've successfully used the method Sean has put forward with shack walls.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid: Did you make sure that the "area of wall" is on the same wall element and not half/half on two wall elements or even a different wall element? To me it looks like the inner conduit is on the second wall from the right (when looking at from outside), while the outer conduit is clearly on the first wall (from the right, seen from outside)

Comment: @dube Dunno what screenshot you're looking at. The outside screenshot clearly shows the conduit placed to the *left* of the border between the two right-most walls. Now, the *interior* shot might not be so clear, but it looks to be close enough.

Comment: @Iszi the interior screenshot. "close enough" is how people think, but computers ususally follow strict rules. If (!) the rule is "have to be connected to the same element", it's obviously important to place them on the same wall tile. I didn't check this myself, but it might be worth trying. But maybe it's just Fallout being Fallout. I often have to place lamps multiple times before they begin to glow, so who knows o_0

Comment: @dube Not so much "Fallout being Fallout" as "Fallout 4 being a Bethesda product", I suspect.

Comment: BTW I checked the solution in general and my own suggestion and I couldn't get it to work. Tried some Wooden and Metal walls without success.

Comment: Tested this against every metal wall, and most of the wooden ones. Zero success.

Answer (score 2):

I have the real answer you are looking for! I had your same question and I just stumbled on the answer. Go to power - conduits - wall pass through. Set one on each side of the wall, they should connect together noticeably. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Many building pieces have small holes in them that can have wires strung through them or conduits placed in them in order to allow inside lighting. For example, take a look at one of the small metal walls you can build

[image]

The top right corner can have wire threaded through it or you can place an upside-down conduit inside it to link wire on both sides.

Many different wall segments allow this in places so experiment to find one that suits your build.

Comment: This more or less fits in with the curved roof solution I've been using. It will still require particularly special placement and tuning of the exterior and interior power links until you can line up the curved path of the cord between them so that it passes through the hole. Also, did you test this? I remember trying some of those walls before, without any luck even when I could a visibly clear line for the cable. Will give it another shot though.

Answer (score 1):

You usually only need power conduits on the *outside* of your building. The power seems to be available inside a sphere or cube around that conduit automatically. So you don't need ugly cabling on the inside, just make sure there are some on the outside.

For example, when you scrap and rebuild the building to the right of the workshop building in Sanctuary, you only need two power conduits on the outside to power most of the building (I built a two-story building here, placed both conduits on the side facing away from the road on the "roof" line of the ground floor).